# haproxy not allowing external traffic through

Tags: haproxy, mesos, mesosphere, marathon

I set up and haproxy on a mesosphere cluster and set up three web servers using marathon. Now I am trying to load balance between them using this config

```
global
  daemon
  log 127.0.0.1 local0
  log 127.0.0.1 local1 notice
  maxconn 4096

defaults
  log         global
  retries     3
  maxconn     2000
  timeout connect  5000
  timeout client  50000
  timeout server  50000

listen stats
  bind 127.0.0.1:9090
  balance
  mode http

listen apiserver
  bind 0.0.0.0:80
  mode tcp
  balance leastconn
  server apiserver-3 10.132.62.240:31000 check
  server apiserver-2 10.132.62.243:31000 check
  server apiserver-1 10.132.62.242:31000 check
```

Now if I am in the VPN I can connect to the server normally - however externally I am unable to do that.Other Services manage to use the ports without problems (both local and global) but haproxy can't seem to work. If I put haproxy in a docker container it works , however I don't want to do that

Comment: `..., but here I can seem to be able to` - this sounds as if there was something missing in your question?!

Comment: Fixed it - added more info

Comment: Can you share the application configuration for the Marathon application? You can get this from the API endpoint `<marathon-ip>:8080/v2/apps`. Please also share the output of `sudo iptables --list`. Thanks!